# If an orthogonal matrix represents a reflection, show that it is symmetric.

Tags: matrices, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

The question is as it says. I am a first-year uni undergraduate student for context. I don't really know how to approach this question.

Any hints/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orthogonal matrix is when $A \cdot A^T = I$. Reflection is when $A \cdot A = I$. Ipso facto $A^T = A$ and so the matrix is symmetric.

Comment: *“Reflection is when $A\cdot A=I$”*. This is a bit inaccurate. If $A$ is a reflection, then $A^2=I$, but the converse is untrue.